# Shorthand for border properties?

Tags: css

Can we shorten :

```
border-top:1px solid black;
border-left:2px solid red;
border-bottom:3px solid green;
border-right:4px solid blue;
```

To something similar to :

```
border:1px solid black 2px solid red 3px solid green 4px solid blue;
```

N.B: I know already this way:

```
border-width:1px 2px 3px 4px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black red green blue;
```

Comment: From the docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-shorthands `Unlike the shorthand ‘margin’ and ‘padding’ properties, the ‘border’ property cannot set different values on the four borders. To do so, one or more of the other border properties must be used.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, you can't make it any shorter than the examples you've provided.

### [From the docs](http://w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-shorthands)

> Unlike the shorthand ‘margin’ and ‘padding’ properties, the ‘border’
> property cannot set different values on the four borders. To do so,
> one or more of the other border properties must be used.

<sub>Thanks @Rocket</sub>

---

If you are using a preprocessor (like SCSS), you could try and use a mixin, but I hardly believe that's what you want:

```
@mixin border_shorthand(
$top_width, $top_color, $top_style,
$left_width, $left_color, $left_style,
$bottom_width, $bottom_color, $bottom_style,
$right_width, $right_color, $right_style) {
  border-top: $top_width $top_color $top_style;
  border-left: $left_width $left_color $left_style;
  border-bottom: $bottom_width $bottom_color $bottom_style;
  border-right: $right_width $right_color $right_style;
}

.element {
  @include border_shorthand(1px, black, solid, 2px, red, solid, 3px, green, solid, 4px, blue, solid);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
.element {
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  border-left: 2px red solid;
  border-bottom: 3px green solid;
  border-right: 4px blue solid; }
```

Comment: I will wait a little bit, maybe someone found something that could interests me.

Comment: @user1365010, he was the first one to correctly answer your very direct "yes/no" question, there is no reason to wait.

Comment: @Sparky672: He wants to see if I might be wrong, and there's a way to do so.

Comment: @Truth: Not with vanilla CSS, but maybe with a CSS framework like SASS or LESS?

Comment: @Truth, I realize that but your answer (and Rocket's comment on the OP) is clearly from the spec.

Comment: @Truth: I don't know much about SASS or LESS.  It was just a thought. :-P